# Bash eval inside quotes

Tags: bash, ssh

I have a bash script which takes one parameter and does something like this:

ssh -t someserver "setenv DISPLAY $1; /usr/bin/someprogram"

How can I force bash to substitute in the $1 instead of passing the literal characters "$1" as the display variable?

Comment: are you sure the quoting is as shown? It should work as shown. Is it possible that $1 doesn't have the value you expect it to have?

Comment: It seems like that should work as is, because bash performs substitution within double quotes...

Comment: `setenv` is only useful in t?csh, is that really what you are running on the remote end?

Comment: Yes I'm running csh on the remote end

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your comment on sehe's answer, it sounds like you just want the remote command to use the local X display — so that the program is running on your remote server (`someserver`) but being displayed on the machine you ran the `ssh` command on.

This can be done by just passing `-X`, e.g.

```
ssh -X someserver /usr/bin/someprogram
```

For some reason, this doesn't work with a few programs, for example `evince`.  I'm not really sure why.  I'm pretty sure that `evince` is the only app I've had trouble forwarding back over an SSH connection.

If this isn't what you're aiming to do, please explain.

Answer (score 1):

**Edit** Are you aware of

```
ssh -X ...
ssh -Y ...
```

which already support X forwarding out of the box? Also look at

```
xhost +
```

in case you need to increase permissions to 'guests'.

If you want to forward non-standard X display address, you could always use

```
DISPLAY=localhost:3 ssh -XCt user@remote xterm
```

**Bonus**: to make ssh background after authentication, add '-f'

What locally? That should already work as shown. Remotely? escape the $: `\$`

However, I'm not sure where the command would be taking it's arguments ($1) from

Comment: If my script is called, runRemoteProgWithDisplay, I want to be able to do ./runRemoteProgWithDisplay 129.1.1.1:1 ....this is currently giving  me an error saying invalid display